# $timeout or $apply cause infinite loop while used in custom filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried to create progress bar for filter operations on large data sets.
But when I tried to use `$rootScope.$apply` or `$timeout` this filter goes in infinite loop and I can't understand why.
When I comment out `sort()` filter works fine. Any ideas?

JS:

```
/* SORT RESULTS BY OBJECT PROPERTY VALUE */
.filter('sortObjectBy', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
  var timeout
    , timeoutHandler
    ;
  timeout = function () {
    if(timeoutHandler && typeof timeoutHandler.cancel === 'function'){
      timeoutHandler.cancel();
    }
    timeoutHandler = $timeout(function () {
      /* ... */
    }, 200);
  };
  return function (data, sortBy, reverse) {
    /* ... */
    timeout();
    return sortArr;
  }
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<tb-filter-row ng-if="parentData"
               ng-repeat="fd in parentData.children | sortObjectBy: sort.sortBy: sort.desc"
               filter-data="fd"></tb-filter-row>
```

**EDIT:**

I tried to create simple fiddle and it seems to be broken too: [**LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/tjruzpmb/24/)

Comment: Idea doesn't make much sense. Why would you need `$timeout` in the filter? Filter should be synchronous

Comment: did you try to utilise Promises ($q in angular DI) to deal with long-executing sorting? then you won't be limited by strict timeouts logic

Comment: @charlietfl it is just an example, the same thing happens when use `$apply` it just interesting

Comment: problem is that digests are complicated and when scope is modified during a digest it forces new digests which is what is happening here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple:

- Digest is called
- To check if value changed or not - angular launches your filter.
- Your filter calls `$apply`.
- $apply starts new Digest.
- To check if value changed or not - angular launches your filter.
- ...

I dont think that displaying of progress bar while your javascript is running is a good idea. Anyway if you want you can do it like this, (you need to run filter manually): 
http://plnkr.co/edit/lBHKjlT7AAJWlPpRwmGJ?p=preview

Keep in mind javascript has one thread only, user cant do anything in browser while javascript is working.